# Need to Remove Web Analytics Completely

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-analytics

We have an issue on our SharePoint 2010 Enterprise site where the WebAnalyticsStaging database has become corrupt and I need to completely remove Web Analytics from the site and then reconfigure it so that it creates new databases and starts fresh. I can find all kinds of articles on how to configure it for use but I have not been able to find anything that tells me how to remove/delete it. Are there any good blogs/articles out there? Does anyone have any advice on this?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1):

From central admin > manage Service Application > Select the Web Analytic and then ribbon select delete it.
after that make sure no related database exist on SQL Server.
http://sp-vinod.blogspot.com/2012/11/cannot-delete-orphaned-web-analytics.html